# App is crashing when it runs on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, crash

I am running my app on simulator, it's working fine , when I am trying to run it on device but I am getting the below error and the app is crashing.

> Error : UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer view message sent to deallocated instance

Can anybody give me the exact reason for this?

Comment: add the exception breakpoint and you will see the exact place where your application is crashed https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html